# Does pionium decay in massless QCD?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, strong-force, pions

The bound state of ${\pi}^+ {\pi}^-$ is called Pionium.

Is Pionium an Electromagnetic bound state or a Strong Force one? then Why?

Does such a bound state last forever if one works in QCD with massless quarks?

In this paper it's mentioned that the width of pionium decay in the Non-relativistic approximation is proportional to the mass difference between charged and neural pion:
[Pionium decay](http://www.iaea.org/inis/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/29/016/29016505.pdf) (equation 1.2)

Comment: If it is mainly held together by the strong force, then shouldn't a $\pi^0\pi^0$ version of pionium exist?

Comment: It is an EM bound state, as ref [17] in your reference details in painstaking detail. If it were a QCD resonance it should be a quark-antiquark state, no? So your "moreover" hypothetical question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Do you understand the lifetime of that resonance would be 8 orders of magnitude ***shorter*** if it were a strong resonance, instead?

Comment: @Cosmas No I don't understand its lifetime has to be exactly 8 orders of magnitude shorter. I wish you could clarify why?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly This actually makes sense to me. But the following ambiguity that arises immediately for me is the possibility of tetraquark exotic hadrons. Why pionium or a hypothetical bound state of two neutral pions can't be envisioned that way around?

Comment: @CosmasZachos "If it were a QCD resonance it should be a quark-antiquark state, no?" 
Of course no. Tetraquarks, Pentaquarks, and exotic mesons are also theoretically possible.

Comment: See my answer .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- It is an ***EM bound state*** like positronium. Its lifetime is $\tau\sim 3\cdot 10^{-15}$sec, characteristic of EM. But, strong lifetimes, think of the ρ !, are $\sim 3\cdot 10^{-15-8}$sec, as you learned in your introductory HEP course, in the systematic understanding of the PDG tables section. Turning off EM would not support this bound state.

A strong bound state would involve quarks and antiquarks bound by gluons. $f_0(500)$ goes into two neutral pions (you know why the  ρ doesn't), and--boy!--it's so short-lived that its status has been debated forever.

Your pionium would "like" to decay to $\pi^+ \pi^-$, but that needs recompense for their binding energy. Since  each charged pion is 5MeV heavier than the neutral pion, it has enough energy to overcome binding and  decays to a pair of neutral pions, with enough energy (and easier to study)!

- But, as the two masses become comparable, this advantage is lost, and, in fact, your [cited reference](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.58.014011) implicitly "goes there" with (6.1) (6.6). Given the (EM) binding energy, *the two-neutral-pion mode would be below threshold too*.  I believe that, nowadays, people estimate such mass differences through chiral perturbation theory and EM perturbation theory.

In fact, as per the OP's bibliographical addition, the second question may be answered more definitely by dint of the conclusions of this paper:[The role of resonances in chiral perturbation theory](https://cds.cern.ch/record/192078/files/198811120.pdf)

Generally speaking, by Dashen's formula, *massless quarks would dictate strictly massless pions*; but quantum fluctuations  QED quantum fluctuations can give rise to some mass for the charged pion, even in the exact chiral limit, where the quarks (and the neutral pion) remain massless (equations 6.5a and 6.5b).

This can trigger the decay of the pionium.

Re: your tetraquark comments, no...  [Effimov strong mesonium threshold bound states](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.100.126023) are out of the picture here, for light quarks. What makes them virtually impossible for light quarks and barely possible for heavy ones is a long story and a very different question, which you should ask precisely and avoiding decision-tree lists.

Comment: So you mean that two pions can't form an exotic meson due to theoretical reasons that are mentioned in the paper you attached namely, since it consists of light quarks?

Comment: Well the pionium you have is certainly  not a tetraquark by dint of lifetime. The [status of hybrids and glueball admixtures](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2020/mobile/reviews/pdf/rpp2020-rev-non-qqbar-mesons-m.pdf) is highly controversial, and almost certainly no light tetraquarks have been established. Theoretical arguments against them are fuzzy, but not as  hopelessly flakey as the ones for them.

Comment: Large N arguments argue against tetraquarks, but have not prevented people from going  down [rabbit holes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.12591).

Comment: I know the arguments of large N. But even large N expansion is pretty much shaky, especially in the case of bryons. Sorry but I don't buy the arguments of a theory whose first order planar diagrams summation isn't done yet and even the correct expansion parameter of it is not well-determined! Though it's mathematically rich and beautiful.

Comment: That's why these are comments and not part of my answer. There is an endless/pointless theoretical discussion, and nothing to buy; as indicated, the arguments *for* diquarks are even worse. This is part of a very different/orthogonal question.  All features of pionium steer you away from it.

Comment: But at the very least do you admit that in massless QCD, pionium is a stable particle?
As equation 6.1 signals in the paper that I attached.
My very concern is that this stability might be ruined by other forms of decay, mainly the decay of pionium to 2 photons.

Comment: In a ludicrously trivial sense: the 2 neutral pion mode would disappear, since it would be degenerate to the two charged pions, which are bound by some binding energy! Of course there would be a 4γ  mode, two photons for each sub-threshold neutral pions. But gapless QCD with strictly massless pseudoscalar bound states would be a very odd beast, to start with! Perhaps lattice types discuss it.

Comment: Indeed, even positronium for massless electrons has an infinite lifetime... you are taking the limit of massless pions bound with *what* binding energy?

Comment: To me, nothing is ludicrous or trivial. A very close example in 2 dimensions to me is the case of the bound state of massless charged fermions that do exist in a very similar fashion due to linear electric potential in QED that resembles QCD effectively.

And unfortunately, you totally ignored the very purpose of the question which is about the MASSLESS QCD, which of course helped me gain some knowledge in other areas.

Comment: Ach, but I thought we had *settled* the binding source: the lifetime  dictates EM, not strong!

Comment: Perhaps the best is to amend the question not to cause further misunderstandings.

Comment: I found the proper answer for the second part. But I agree about the first question.